# How to calculate itemHeights in CustomVirtualStrategy

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

Im using `CdkVirtualScrollViewport` in my project it is chat and when new message comes I make `scrollTo({bottom: 0})` but it goes little bit higher I think the issue is different `hegiht` of each message as I'm using `textarea` which can have several new lines. Ive read this [article](https://indepth.dev/posts/1091/writing-custom-virtual-scroll-strategy) and they calcualte the hight dynamically. Also Ive read about a `setTimeout` on scroll bottom but it is not a best option. Do you know how the `itemHeight` can be calcuatied ?

Comment: If you have textareas that increase their height when there is lot of text, you cannot reliably calculate result height without rendering all them. Your scroll height in this case cannot be calculated as well (you should have noticed some scroll flickering)

Usual solution here is re-design, e.g. you can make all messages 2-line and expand them on hover.

Comment: is it limitation of lib ? as I dont see such issue in any messenger